# flutter Hive getRange

Tags: flutter, hive

i'm  using Hive as my local storage and i need a method similar to getRange method which return the values between 2 specific numbers but the getRange method is not defined with Hive

`testBox = await Hive.openBox('testBox');`
`List<double> progressData = testBox.getRange(startIndex, endIndex + 1).map<double>((e) => e.toDouble()).toList();`

there is an error under getRange because its not supported as i said. but i cant figure out what is the alternative method to help me to return the same logic as this line of code

is it possible to solve that ?